# java.lang.NumberFormatException when getting a length of an array in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

I'm trying to access a length property of a String[][] array but getting a `NumberFormatException`.

My JSP code

```
    <c:set var="len" value="${Constants.CATEGORIES.length}"/>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${len}" step="1" varStatus ="status">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="">${Constants.CATEGORIES[i][0]}</a>
    </c:forEach>
```

Below is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:115)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.shared.categories_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(categories_jsp.java:146)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.shared.categories_jsp._jspService(categories_jsp.java:107)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.home.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:133)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.raghavpro.bookhive.controllers.home.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:76)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same problem by using the JSTL function `length`.
Add the taglib at the beginning of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Then, in your JSP you can do `${ fn:length(Constants.CATEGORIES) }`

Answer (score -1):

end="${length}" doesn't seems to contain the value,instead it is passing the string "length" and hence the exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "length"
```

check the expression end="${length}"